# Does H2O support one-class classification?

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, h2o, one-class-classification

I'd like to build a [one-class classification (OCC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-class_classification) model using the H2O package either for Python or R but I couldn't find any reference on the internet. So I wonder, does H2O support one-class classification? If it does, could someone here help me to give an example code to do it using the Setosa class from the [Iris Dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/iris) and then test it to predict the other classes?

Answer (score 0):

In python you can use the One-Class Support Vector Machine implementation in scikit-learn:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.OneClassSVM.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm only interested in using the H2O package.